# How should we refer to the series formed by the terms of the harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

As we know harmonic progression is the list of numbers where reciprocal of the terms are in AP.

So if one takes sum of the terms of harmonic progression, then the series formed should be called as harmonic series or something else?

Actually harmonic series is specifically defined as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}$, so that's why it is ambiguous to refer every series as harmonic series. For instance:

If we have harmonic progression as $\{1,\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{5},\dfrac{1}{7}\cdots\}$, then the series formed by the terms of this progression should be called as harmonic series or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Let's hope I understood your question correctly.

When we mention the harmonic series, we always refer to this sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

and if we're talking about any other possible partial sum, then the notation for sums "sums" it up, by which I mean we get all the information about that sum that we need:

$$\sum_{n=k}^m \frac{1}{n}$$ for $m,\,k\in\mathbb N$.

Now, if you want to talk about another sum, maybe the sum over all reciprocals (i.e. harmonic numbers) which are the squares of an integer, then notation is still the key: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Finally, there could be an instance where one needs to define a subset of the integers that specifies a property, and then describe the sum one wants to take over those numbers. Maybe it's a homework exercise, so it would look like this:

Let S = $\{n\in\mathbb N |\ \text{n has 12 digits, none of which are 3} \}$
, and for $n\in S$ find the value of I:

$$\text{I =} \ \sum_{n=127124125126}^{217214215216} \frac{1}{\lfloor \sqrt[55]{n} \rfloor}$$

As far as I can tell, there is no ambiguity, again assuming I understood your question correctly. I hope this helps. Finally, I would suggest adding the tag of "notation" to this question.